# Synonym proposal [cypressio] -> [cypress]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Currently two tags are being used for the E2E testing tool [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/):

- [cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cypress) - 3,422 questions, has a tag wiki; and
- [cypressio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cypressio) - 24 questions (virtually all tagged with "cypress" too, none about anything other than this tool), no tag wiki.

I suggest that the latter be made a synonym of the former.

Comment: "Is [cypressio] over the hill?"

Comment: Only 2 questions had [cypress] added in the merge